# a meeting of his Likud Party faction

Tags: word-meaning

> "I am determined to pass this bill with or without consensus," Netanyahu told **a meeting** of his Likud Party faction last month. "It is very important for securing the future of the nation of Israel, in the Land of Israel, in the State of Israel." *(Canada stays mum on controversial Israeli bill - CBC news Dec.14 2014)*

Does "a meeting" here mean "a group of people"?

Comment: It means an occasion on which people meet - in this case, members of Netanyahu's faction.

Comment: So, you can tell 'an occasion' something as in "She told me everything."?

Comment: @StoneyB: Actually, it's a synedoche (or summat like that), since the "meeting" is the occasion/event/gathering, but he actually told ***the people attending the meeting***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It might be a metonymy rather than a synecdoche. I'm not entirely sure which is technically more correct, but I enjoyed researching both terms, so thanks for helping me exceed my "learn one new thing a day" quota :)  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15415/what-is-the-difference-between-metonymy-and-synecdoche

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word *meeting* can be used in the meaning of either an occasion (that people meet) or the people in a meeting. In *Netanyahu told **a meeting** of his Likud Party faction last month,* it makes more sense to understand it as "a group of people", as you suggested.

From Macmillan Dictionary:

> **[meeting](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/meeting)**
>   <sup>noun [countable]</sup>
>   1. an occasion when people gather to discuss things and make decisions, either in person or using phones, the Internet, etc.
>   ​　　a. [formal] the people involved in a meeting
>   ​　　　　*I reported to the meeting on my progress.*
>   ​　　b. an occasion when two people meet either unexpectedly or as planned
>   ​　　　　*I liked him from our first meeting.*